# Delete records from cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, elassandra

I have written wrong update command.

```
update table_name set col_val = 'x' where PRI_KEY_1 IN ( 50 values ) and PRI_KEY_2 IN ( 50 values ) and CLUSTER_KEY IN ( 10 Values );
```

This has created 40000 records where there was only 150. I can see only columns mentioned in query- PRI_KEY_1 ,PRI_KEY_2 and CLUSTER_KEY are updated in those extra 39850.

Now I need help in deleting all those 39850 records. Please Help.

Comment: UPDATE _creates_ no rows.

Comment: I can see 40000 records created.

Comment: `INSERT` _creates/inserts_ rows. `UPDATE` _updates_ rows.

Comment: @jarlh Cassandra treats all writes (INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs) the same.  Thus, Cassandra allows you to update a value with an INSERT, and insert rows with UPDATE.

Comment: And DELETE rows with an INSERT?

Comment: @jarlh If you want to think about it that way, DELETEs insert a tombstone.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn't a quick fix for it.

You will need to iterate over those records and issue a `DELETE`.

Comment: You mean delete 39850 record ??? by entering each command

Comment: You can script it, but yes. There isn't a magic bullet. Sorry.

Comment: one last thing , how to run script in cassandra?I mean can we run it when ./cqlsh is running?

Comment: @CaptainLevii you can't actually run a script in Cassandra.  Erick is saying that you'll have to "script"-out the logic using something like Python.

Comment: Plus 1 to @Aaron's response. :)